# Drop google fonts dependency

Tags: semantic-ui-react

I'm currently building a web app which is intended to run on an isolated, offline environment. However, semantic imports fonts from Google's datacenter by default (a terrible practice if you ask me), which obviously aren't reachable from this environment, hanging the app for 10 or 20 seconds until it times out.

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?

I've read things about gulp here and there, but honestly I don't even know what gulp is. All I've used is npm/yarn.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using gulp is your most reliable approach, and this guide makes it easy to follow:

http://g14n.info/2016/11/react-semantic-customized/

Your second option would be to use a forked version of their CSS like this one:

https://github.com/arthurlacoste/semantic-ui-offline